# property of Baire and Borel sets

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

I know that every Borel set has the property of Baire. I know also that the opposite theorem is not true - there exists sets which have the property of Baire ad they are not Borel sets. What is an example of this kind of set? (with property of Baire but not Borel)

Comment: I need an exact example of set which has the property of Baire but it's not a Borel set.

Comment: The middle-thirds Cantor set $C$ is meager (in $\mathbb R$), and therefore so are all its subsets. So any non-Borel subset of $C$ can serve as you example.  (P.S. The questions linked by @Henry are about Baire sets, not sets with the Baire property.)

Comment: Forget about the property of Baire for a moment. Do you know how to give an example of *any* set which is not Borel?

Comment: @AndreasBlass From which theorem we know that there exists subsets of Cantor set which are non-Borel? In which books can I find this informations?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I suppose we should use axiom of choice but I don't know exactly from which theorem we know that for example Cantor set has non-Borel subsets

Comment: @mat123 On this site, users are expected to demonstrate that they've put in some effort themselves before asking questions here (see the advice [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/7062)). My point is that if you're looking for a non-Borel set with the property of Baire, the most obvious place to start is to look at some examples of non-Borel sets and see if they have the property of Baire or can be modified to have the property of Baire. If you don't know any examples of non-Borel sets, you should do more research, or you should be asking this more basic question!

Comment: I agree with @AlexKruckman because (1) if you know an example of a non-Borel set (in $\mathbb R$ or even in $\mathbb R^n$), it's not hard to manipulate it to get an example in the Cantor set, and (2) if you don't know an example of a non-Borel set, then you should study that before worrying about the Baire property.